# In openfire how to create custom bot

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have a requirement where n chat-rooms each having x number participants, I need to run bot in openfire to listen to all the messages and for each message I am sending custom attribute like `department="sales",department="manager"`. So, based on the custom attribute, I need to push data to different REST API endpoints.I have heard about `XMPP Bot over Channels` but didn't get anything about this. So, how can I implement the above scenario using bots.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could tackle this. The easiest approach would probably be to write an Openfire plugin that uses a PacketInterceptor to listen for the stanzas of interest. You can read up on how to develop Openfire plugins in https://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html

Another approach would be to create a custom client that you somehow make join all chatrooms that are of interest to you. As your client would join the chatroom as any other occupant, it will receive the messages that are shared in that room - and again, you can act accordingly.

The former solution probably scales best, and probably is the least complex. The latter solution would be easier to run as a stand-alone process, and would allow you to use different APIs than the one provided by Openfire.

Comment: but instead of intercepting all messages, I wanted to create a bot which will login as bot user and the bot needs to join all the muc groups that it has been added to and needs to recieved message to a REST API. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that's basically the second option that I gave. You will have to create some kind of XMPP client that the boy can use, make sure that it joins the relevant MUC rooms, and that does the REST API interaction.